# Creating random array with 50 items / Just 0 and 1

Tags: c#

I need to code so;

There will be one array with randomly 50 items (only 0 and 1).Each row has 5 items and it will be 10 rows totally.
Level1 : 
Each row have 4 zeros and 1 one (like 001000; 10000;010000;00010 etc)
Level2:
Each row have 3 zeros and 2 ones (like 01010;11000;00011;10010 etc)
this will continued so that..

Actually, zeros presented greens, ones presented reds. I will make a game that contains 5x10 buttons. When user cliked green button he will be pass to next row. If he clicked red button he will lose.

I wrote something but that isn't i wanted. Please help :(

```
 int maxGreenCount = 5;
int maxRedCount = 1;

public int GenerateNumber()
{
    int numbervalue;

    numbervalue = Random.Range(0, 2);
    return numbervalue;
}

public int[] GenerateRow()
{
    int[] rowfinal = new int[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {

            if (GenerateNumber() == 0)
            {
                if (greenCount < maxGreenCount)
                {
                    rowfinal[i] = 0;
                    greenCount++;
                }

            }

            if (GenerateNumber() == 1)
            {
                if (RedCount < maxRedCount)
                {
                    rowfinal[i] = 1;
                    RedCount++;
                }

            }

            RedCount = 0;
            greenCount = 0;
        }
    }
    return rowfinal;
}
```

I expect this:

[image]

Comment: You need to flesh out the question. You haven't explained what you expect.

Comment: Hi Sean. I expect that in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq :

```
            Random rand = new Random();

            var results = Enumerable.Range(1,4)
                .Select(level => Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(row => Enumerable.Repeat(1,level).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5 - level))
                    .Select(column => new { column = column, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.column).ToArray())
                    .ToArray())
                    .ToArray();
```

---

Below gives a two dimension array

```
            int[][] results = Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
                .Select(level => Enumerable.Range(1, 10).SelectMany(row => Enumerable.Repeat(1, level).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5 - level))
                    .Select(column => new { column = column, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.column)).ToArray())
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi jdweng i wont use database. It is simple game made in Unity and coding with C#

Comment: Linq is not a database tool.  It is strictly a Net Library feature.

Comment: Thanks jdweng but Can't you figure out via classical C# codes?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the code you generated and didn't like.

Comment: How can I add results to an int or string array? I tried foreach but it didn't work.

Comment: It is very very complicated buddy. results is an 3d array. I can't this resolve to simple array

Comment: I updated code to give a two dimensional array of int.

Comment: @djweng Thanks my friend. What are first dimension and second dimension of this array? How can I use this? If you help, I will mark as answer your post.

Comment: Array size is 4 x 50.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cant understand but I am marking as answer. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all replies